# Different text on different sites in a multisite setup

Tags: theme-development, multisite

I have a multisite setup with say two websites and both of them use the same theme.

Now, I want to use the same theme for both of the websites but **want to change texts** in few places. say the "read more" button in website1 should show "show more" for website2.

What solution I have thought of:

Duplicating the theme. And then change the texts in the duplicated version and activate that for my second theme.

I guess that will work. But I thought to ask this question to know if there is a better way to do it with a plugin or some code to detect which site I am on.

Since using a duplicate theme, I might have to repeat myself when I do some design changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a child theme of that theme and do the modifications. This way you don't need to repeat everything. Just do the modification in the child theme and it will work as the parent theme with your modifications.